# How do we check if mock request is actually the correct one?

Tags: python, mocking, python-requests

Since we return mock objects from the requests made by the code, this means that no matter the input to the code under test, as long as the response from the request is handled correctly, the test would always pass. However we don't know if the code made the right request(s) to my site in the first place. For example, if `makeRequest()` for some reason made a request to `www.my-site.com/foobar` or `www.google.com` we would get a false positive because the tests would still pass since the mock response is still what we expect, but they should really fail.

Probably a silly question, but is there a way in [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to check and make sure the request made is what we expect as well?

```
def makeRequest(session):
    resp = session.get(www.my-site.com/foobar)
    return resp
```

```
@patch.object(requests.Session, 'get')
def test_makeRequest(self, mock_get):
    def mockResp(self):
        r = requests.Response()
        req.status_code = 200
        return r

    mock_get.return_value = mockResp()
    mock_get_response = makeRequest()
```

Comment: The package requests-mock allows exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the request parameters by using assertions on the mock.

```
# setting up the canned response on the mock
mock_get.return_value = mockResp()

# actually calls the real code under test, i.e. calls makeRequest
mock_get_response = makeRequest() 

# make an assertion about what the code *within* makeRequest did
mock_get.assert_called_once_with("www.my-site.com/foobar")

# maybe make an assertion about the `mock_get_response` here, too
```

Note that, as written, this test will fail. You need to pass a session into `makeRequest`, since it takes one required argument. Rather than setup your mock on `requests.Session`, it will be easier to just pass in your mock as the session argument during the test.